# Approximate matching of two lists of events (with duration)

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching

I have a black box algorithm that analyses a time series and "detects" certain events in the series. It returns a list of events, each containing a start time and end time. The events do not overlap.
I also have a list of the "true" events, again with start time and end time for each event, not overlapping.

I want to compare the two lists and match detected and true events that fall within a certain time tolerance (True Positives). The complication is that the algorithm may detect events that are not really there (False Positives) or might miss events that were there (False Negatives).

What is an algorithm that optimally pairs events from the two lists and leaves the proper events unpaired? I am pretty sure I am not the first one to tackle this problem and that such a method exists, but I haven't been able to find it, perhaps because I do not know the right terminology.

Speed requirement:
The lists will contain no more than a few hundred entries, and speed is not a major factor. Accuracy is more important. Anything taking less than a few seconds on an ordinary computer will be fine.

Comment: How many intervals? How quickly?

Comment: Can you end up with a scenario where the best candidate not considering other events in this list is not the best candidate overall? So say all events are 1 hour long, and one list has 3 events starting at 5,6 and 7. The other has events starting at 5.31, 6.31 and 7.31. If only looking at 6, you'd conclude that 5.31 is the best event, but that will leave 5 unpaired. Is this the desired behaviour or should it pair all of them in this example? Also, where exactly is the threshold where it should say events are too far to pair?

Comment: Edited the question to answer the comment by @David.

Comment: My current answer assumes a one-to-one pairing; is it possible that one true event gives rise to several detected events, or vice versa?

Comment: @Dukeling: Ideally the algorithm would sacrifice the "matching quality" of one pair if that helps the matching of others. In your example I would want to pair all of them. I am not exactly sure what you mean by "where is the threshold", but I imagine a maximum value for the difference between the starting times and ending time of a pair candidate to allow pairing. If it is possible to take the differences into account as a weighing factor that would be even better.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes, both are possible: a true event giving rise to multiple detected events and multiple true events giving rise to a single detected events. However, having those remain unpaired I would consider a feature of the matching algorithm, not a shortcoming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quadratic-time algorithm that gives a maximum likelihood estimate with respect to the following model. Let A1 < ... < Am be the true intervals and let B1 < ... < Bn be the reported intervals. The quantity sub(i, j) is the log-likelihood that Ai becomes Bj. The quantity del(i) is the log-likelihood that Ai is deleted. The quantity ins(j) is the log-likelihood that Bj is inserted. Make independence assumptions everywhere! I'm going to choose sub, del, and ins so that, for every i < i' and every j < j', we have

```
sub(i, j') + sub(i', j) <= max {sub(i, j )       + sub(i', j')
                               ,del(i) + ins(j') + sub(i', j )
                               ,sub(i, j')       + del(i') + ins(j)
                               }.
```

This ensures that the optimal matching between intervals is noncrossing and thus that we can use the following [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)-like dynamic program.

The dynamic program is presented as a memoized recursive function, `score(i, j)`, that computes the optimal score of matching A1, ..., Ai with B1, ..., Bj. The root of the call tree is `score(m, n)`. It can be modified to return the sequence of `sub(i, j)` operations in the optimal solution.

```
score(i, j) | i == 0 && j == 0 =      0
            | i >  0 && j == 0 =      del(i)    + score(i - 1, 0    )
            | i == 0 && j >  0 =      ins(j)    + score(0    , j - 1)
            | i >  0 && j >  0 = max {sub(i, j) + score(i - 1, j - 1)
                                     ,del(i)    + score(i - 1, j    )
                                     ,ins(j)    + score(i    , j - 1)
                                     }
```

Here are some possible definitions for sub, del, and ins. I'm not sure if they will be any good; you may want to multiply their values by constants or use powers other than 2. If Ai = [s, t] and Bj = [u, v], then define

```
sub(i, j) = -(|u - s|^2 + |v - t|^2)
del(i) = -(t - s)^2
ins(j) = -(v - u)^2.
```

(Apologies to the undoubtedly extant academic who published something like this in the bioinformatics literature many decades ago.)

Comment: (With significantly more difficulty, one could alternatively implement the cubic-time Hungarian algorithm and do away with the assumptions required for noncrossing matchings. I'm not sure what the point would be.)